# stubbornly floating to the right although there is no command

Tags: jquery, html, css

**http://jsfiddle.net/6j7zC** why is the adminbox floating although there is no command?

http://jsfiddle.net/6j7zC/1** the fixed div center not working properly

```
.adminbox
{
        width: 200px;    
        height: 17px;
        margin-top: 20px;  
        padding: 20px; 
        font-size: 12px;   
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        font-size: 12px;           
        font-family:"Gears of Peace";
}
```

Comment: did you try by giving putting "float:left" ?

Comment: @Aveendra yes float:left makes it margin auto. I dunno why.

Comment: Um, there is a `float:right;` command in the CSS for the adminbox in the first fiddle. It would help if you kept only one rule per line so you'd see them better.

Comment: float:left; margin-left:0px;  This could fix you problem.

Comment: its because of the padding, you have given 20px padding there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lines 57-61 of the css...

```
.adminbox
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 35px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: auto;
    color: green;
    background-color: transparent;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

There's a float: right in there ;)

Comment: thank you. I made an edit to my question thank you very much.

Comment: what about the 2# question?

Comment: At the moment it's doing all your CSS is asking it to do. A common fix would be to say left/right: 50%; and then add a negative margin half of the div's width.

For instance:

.password
{position: fixed; width: 370px; left: 50%; margin-left: -185px;}

Answer (score 0):

For your second question; it's exactly drawing your box as per your css

```
top: 50%;    right: 50%;
```

and you have mention width and height to the password box

`width: 370px;    height: 200px;`

There is noting unusual as per your code behavior on the output.

**Your query is not clear; what resolution you are targeting your POC/website/app?**

Comment: How can I make it exact middle of the screen?

Comment: Please research on stack-overflow; questions similar to positioning center is already there with the solutions.